# Convergence in probability and equivalence from convergence almost sure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

We all know that almost sure implies probability convergence: $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ implies $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$. A counterexample example for the converse is

\begin{eqnarray*}
X_1 &=& 1 \\
X_2 &=& I_{[0,1/2]}(U) \\
X_3 &=& I_{[1/2,1]}(U) \\
X_4 &=& I_{[0,1/4]}(U) \\
X_5 &=& I_{[1/4,1/2]}(U) \\
X_6 &=& I_{[1/2,3/4]}(U) \\
X_7 &=& I_{[3/4,1]}(U) \\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray*}
where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $I$ is the indicator function. So, for $n = 2^k + m$ ($m < 2^k$), $X_n = I_{[m2^{-k},(m+1)2^{-k}]}(U)$. For this, $X_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$ but $X_n$ doesn't converge almost sure  to $0$ because the sequence eventually gets the value $1$ infinitely many times, no matter the value of $U$.

In Thomas Ferguson we got the following result

> $X_n\xrightarrow{p} X$ if and only if every subsequence $n_1, n_2,\dots \in \{1,2,3,\dots
> \}$ has a sub-sequence $m_1,m_2,\dots \in \{n_1, n_2, \dots\}$ such that $X_{m_j} \xrightarrow{a.s} X$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.

So, since $X_n \xrightarrow{p}0$ for the sequence above, I should be able to find (given an outcome $U 
\in [0,1]$ and a subsequence $X_{n_k}$) a sub-subsequence $X_{m_j}$ that converges to $0$ almost sure.

My question is, let say I give you the output $1/2$ and the subsequence $X_{n_j}$ of the form $n_j = 2^k +m$ such that $m2^{-k} = 1/2$. So $X_{n_j} = 1$ for all $n_j$. How can I extract a subsequence from $n_j$ that converges to $0$ if every term is $1$? What am I misinterpreting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should be able to find (given an outcome $U \in [0,1]$ and a subsequence $X_{n_k}$) a subsequence $X_{m_j}$ that converges to $0$ almost surely.

This is a misinterpretation. Note that "given $U$" there is no longer any randomness so the limit you are considering is just a usual [non-random] limit. Furthermore, the subsequence $(m_j)$ should not depend on $U$.

The correct interpretation is as follows. Given a subsequence $X_{n_j}$, there exists a further subsequence $X_{m_j}$ such that $P(X_{m_j} \to 0) = 1$. In particular, this does not prevent $X_{m_j} \not\to 0$ from happening for certain values of $U$; it only states that such situations happen with probability $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what is the correct/rigorous way to demonstrate what I want? Before your answer, I was thinking something like, if the first subsequence $n_j$ doesn't take the indices that make the value of $X_{n_j} = 1$, then my subsequence is $0$ for all terms and that's it. If this doesn't happen, I can take a further subsequence by removing those indices and since there're a countable amount of them, they form a measure-zero set. Thanks again